# Daily Bandwidth monitoring graph

Tags: zabbix

I am very new to the subject and trying to create a graph to capture daily bandwidth usage for a one month period. However unable to reset counter at 23:59H.

Managed to get the total usage graph using below formula. (DPS is the device I am monitoring) last("dpsTotalOutboundBytes")+last("totalfwdvolume")

enter image description here

Can you please help me to finish the task?

Thanks for your support! 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Mqk.png)Mahesh